# My program edits a text file. Why is text file sometimes empty at startup when it contained data when i close down my computer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner at C# and programming in general, so this problem might be simple for others.

I've created a program that performs a certain task on every .dwg file that is saved in specific folders that the user specifies. (The specific task is not important for this issue.) The folders are stored in a textfile which can be edited by the user via a form that I have set up. So the user can add or remove folders to the list, which is then saved as a txt-file. The program seems to be working when I try it out, but the thing I can't figure out is why the textfile containing the folders is sometimes completely empty when I start my computer, even though it contained lines of folders when I turned off the computer (the program is set to autorun at startup). It must be due to my poor coding, but I can't figure out why. Can anyone help a beginner out?

```
/////////Form.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Window;

namespace Form_List
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string cadPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\AutoCAD 2022";
        //private Program programInstance = new Program();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string Folder_text_path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                if (listBox1.Items.Contains(Folder_text_path) == false)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(Folder_text_path);
                    lbl_notification.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + " was added to the list.";
                    Program.foldersToMonitor.Add(Folder_text_path);
                    Program.SaveFoldersToMonitor();
                    File.WriteAllLines("folders.txt", Program.foldersToMonitor);
                    Program.StartMonitoring();
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_notification.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + " already exists in the list.";
                }
            }
        }

        private void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
                lbl_notification.Text = "No item was selected.";
            else
            {
                string folderToRemove = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                lbl_notification.Text = folderToRemove + " was removed from the list.";
                Program.foldersToMonitor.Remove(folderToRemove);
                listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
                File.WriteAllLines("folders.txt", Program.foldersToMonitor);
                Program.SaveFoldersToMonitor();
                Program.StartMonitoring();
            }
        }

        public void btn_Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Path.Text))
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(txt_Path.Text))
                {
                    if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(txt_Path.Text))
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(txt_Path.Text);
                        Program.foldersToMonitor.Add(txt_Path.Text);
                        lbl_notification.Text = txt_Path.Text + " was added to the list.";
                        txt_Path.Text = "";
                        Program.SaveFoldersToMonitor();
                        File.WriteAllLines("folders.txt", Program.foldersToMonitor);
                        Program.StartMonitoring();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbl_notification.Text = txt_Path.Text + " already exists in the list.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_notification.Text = txt_Path.Text + " is not a valid directory.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_notification.Text = "Enter a path to add it to the list.";
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> lines = ReadLinesFromFile();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(lines.ToArray());

            // Set the cadPath variable to the first line of the autocadpath.txt file
            cadPath = ReadFirstLineFromFile("autocadpath.txt");
            lbl_CadPath.Text = cadPath;
        }

        private string ReadFirstLineFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            string firstLine = string.Empty;
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                firstLine = File.ReadLines(filePath).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return firstLine;
        }

        private void lbl_Info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txt_Path_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public ListBox.ObjectCollection ListBoxItems
        {
            get { return listBox1.Items; }
        }

        private List<string> ReadLinesFromFile()
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            string filePath = "folders.txt";
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(line))
                    {
                        lines.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            return lines;
        }

        private void btn_CadPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                lbl_CadPath.Text = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;

                cadPath = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;

                // Write the selected path to the autocadpath.txt file
                File.WriteAllText("autocadpath.txt", cadPath);
            }            
        }
    }
}`
```

I've only pasted the code that I figured was relevant.

I've tried reviewing the code, but as there are no error messages I can't find the problem.

Comment: You are just using the file name for loading and saving without specifying the path where this file should be located. That means, the current working directory will be assumed as the location of the file. The current working directory can be different between different program runs depending on a number of factors, including how and in which environment your program is started. I bet this is at the heart of your issue.

Comment: Just for funsies and if you are interested, assign the value of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` (this is the value of the current working directory) to some text label or the window title in your program and see what the current working directory is when you start your program in different ways (like inside and outside of the debugger, or through your autostart link file, for example...)

Comment: You may also want to consider using user settings for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8